# Problem saving object to DynamoDB using Dynamoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I tried to create rails 6 (ruby version: 2.6.3) project using Dynamoid to store data in my DynamoDB database.

To make sure my data is saved correctly in dynamoDB, I followed the configuration step mentioned in the README file (https://github.com/Dynamoid/dynamoid).
I create a user model as following:

```rb
class User
  include Dynamoid::Document

  field :name
end
```

After configuration, I tried to save a user using the rails console.

As a result, I have this error :

```rb
2.6.3 :012 > u = User.create(name: 'John')
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):12
NoMethodError (undefined method `force_change' for #<ActiveModel::NullMutationTracker:0x00007faf8e24bef0>)
```

Anybody had the same issue? 
Dimanoid is supported by rails 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Github issue](https://github.com/Dynamoid/dynamoid/issues/366), the Dynamoid gem does not support rails 6